# Can not compile Nutch1.4 with ant

Tags: ant, hadoop, nutch

all
I'm trying to deploy Nutch1.4 to Hadoop cluster(following [this page](http://www.rui-yang.com/develop/build-nutch-1-4-cluster-with-hadoop/)). I got some problems when compiling Nutch with ant.

#### problem 1

When I run ant command, I got the following error:

> /home/xenserver/apache-nutch-1.4-bin/build.xml:71: invalid Date syntax in "01/25/1971 2:00 pm"

I remove attribute "datetime" from line 71 in file build.xml and run ant again. Then I got another problem.

#### problem 2

The error is:

> /home/xenserver/apache-nutch-1.4/build.xml:412: syntax errors in ivy file: java.text.ParseException: http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxp/properties/schemaLanguage in file:/home/xenserver/apache-nutch-1.4/ivy/ivy.xml
>      at org.apache.ivy.plugins.parser.xml.XmlModuleDescriptorParser$Parser.parse(XmlModuleDescriptorParser.java:273)
>
> ........

What's wrong with the steps above? Is there any tutorial for compiling Nutch1.4?
Need your help.Thanks in advance.

Comment: I just tried to build Nutch on Windows. It works fine...So wired...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For compiling nutch 1.4, all you have to do is run `ant clean deploy` from the nutch directory. The output is created in the directory named '`runtime`' with 2 folders: one for local mode and other one for cluster mode.

please check the date settings and `ant` installation on your machine. I think that is casing the issue. Also have you tampered/ edited `/home/xenserver/apache-nutch-1.4/ivy/ivy.xml` ? Please check that file too.

**EDIT:**

There is some problem with the build file when executed on your Linux box. 
Check these out: [this](http://osdir.com/ml/search.nutch.devel/2005-02/msg00082.html) and [this](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.search.nutch.devel/3436).

These are the things that you should verify on your setup:

1. `java version` and `ant version` : dont use old ones. get the latest ones or ones that are compatible with your nutch release. FYI: for nutch-1.4 I am using apache-ant-1.8.3 and java jdk1.6.0_18. This combination works perfectly fine with me.
2. Check that you have installed a **JDK and not a JRE**
3. Check if your `JAVA_HOME` environment variable point to the JDK. System `PATH` variable must have `$JAVA_HOME/bin` and `$ANT_HOME/bin` appended to it. `ANT_HOM`E variable must point to the ant installation directory.
4. Can you successfully run normal ant targets on any other build files ? try out with small ant build file.
5. Still facing the same issue, run ant command with -v option. This will provide more information about the error faced.
   eg.

   ant -v clean deploy

Comment: I just ran `ant clean deploy`,but still got the ` invalid Date syntax ` problem. How to check the date setting? The problems just occur on Linux platform and it works fine on Windows.

Comment: and I ran `ant clean deploy` command in the original nutch directory with no file edited.

Comment: see my EDIT above..hope that helps :)

Comment: Ohh,It's the jdk problem. My jdk version is too old. It works fine with jdk 1.6. Thanks.

Comment: Hi TejasP, Now I can crawl and index the web pages using Nutch, but I don't know how to read the index and extract data from it. Could you please introduce to me some useful tools to read the index? I want to add a Chinese Language Analyzer and a IndexFilter plugin, so I want to read the index to validate my plugin. And also,I want to do some process with the data I crawled. Thanks.

Comment: this is unrelated to the previous issue. please create a new question so that your issue gets ample attention from everybody in SO.

Comment: Use luke tool to browse the nutch indexes :
http://code.google.com/p/luke/source/browse/wiki/img/overview.png

Comment: To read the crawled content, use the nutch segment reader:
http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/nutch-0.8-dev/bin/nutch_segread

Comment: Thank you for the details:). I have post it in a new question.

Comment: Hi,@TejasP, There is something incorrect in your answer. Run `ant clean deploy` can not generate the 'runtime' directory. Please correct your answer. Thanks.

Comment: It depends on the nutch version u r using. For nutch-1.0 , "ant clean deploy" works..For nutch 1.4, "ant runtime" will do it.

Comment: I understand,but your answer said for nutch 1.4 run "ant clean deploy". It will confuse others new guys. :)